# How to parse a word from an autocomplete suggestion in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my code here - http://jsbin.com/civimivihe/edit?html,output

What it does is, when a user keys in some text in the input box a list of suggestions appear using jQuery's auto-complete.

However when a user selects a value from the suggestions, I want only the first word to appear in the textbox.

I am stuck with modifying the select event. Any suggestions on how to parse the first word alone?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] to your question. Links can be unavailable at any given time making the question incomplete and thus, impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the end of the [jQueryUI](http://www.jqueryui.com)'s [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) Ajax JS code from this...

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
   return ui.item.label;
}
```

To this... Then it will leave the stock ticker's code in the input field.

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
   var labelPieces = ui.item.label.split(' ');
   setTimeout(function() {
       $('#stock').val(labelPieces[0]);
   },0);
}
```

The jQuery Autocomplete API documentation can be found at: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Note: The setTimeout 0 value allows the jQueryUI library to finish up its processing work for its autocomplete feature, before the value is parsed and inserted into the input field. The 0 value creates an asynchronous timer. It can be adjusted upward as needed. (Remember to use milliseconds, instead of seconds.)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you for the explanation and references :)